# for loop query in java

Tags: java, for-loop

```
      for(int x=0;; ) {
      System.out.println(x);
       x++;
           }
```

The o/p of the code is as below:

```
1521760

1521761

1521762

1521763

1521764

1521765

1521766

1521767

1521768

1521769

1521770

1521783

1521784
```

Can anyone please explain instead  of printing 0 for infinite times why this is printing these random numbers?

Comment: ...because `x=0` and `x` doesn't change and you also don't break your loop with any kind of ending condition...?

Comment: those are the value of x (which you increase by x++), you never put a break, or set a limit to your loop

Comment: They don't seem random to me, it's an arithmetic sequence. BTW why did you expect _'0 for infinite times'_...??

Comment: These are not random numbers. It runs and prints from 0 so fast that's why you are not able to see it.

Comment: Please provide clearer formatting and context in your questions. It's hard to read such questions.

Comment: What does "o/p" mean?

Comment: @Scratte I've never seen it used this way, but I'd guess "output."

Answer (score 3):

It is printing from 0 to all the way up. But processor runs so fast (it has already ran until 1521760), so you directly start seeing from those high values.

You can check by putting break (or doing debugging by putting breakpoints in `x++` line) as below,

```
for(int x=0;; ) {
            System.out.println(x);
            x++;
            if(x == 10)
                break;
        }
```

//output as

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are incrementing variable x inside for loop block. Although, you not increment x inside loop statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a random number if you run the same code in a different machine(Which has a different processor) most probably you will get a different number, but it's not because they are Random numbers. It's because of the processors' speed difference.So normally processors process programs at a speed that we can't even think, So here also your processor already incremented your value up to a certain limit that's why you see something like that.you can check it by breaking the code in a particular condition like in the above answer. But you can see what's happening there in a **much more detailed manner by debugging the code. Then you can see the incrementing process of x**